# Python <> MS ACCESS filter by date

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, cursor

I connected python to MS Access using pyodbc

I want to delete rows from table based on date criteria (date greater then)

my code:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
r'DBQ=C:\***\Test.accdb')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('DELETE FROM `# Euromedica` WHERE Date > 2022-01-09')
cursor.commit()
```

after code execution I have an empty table.
How can I properly filter by Date?

Comment: 2022-01-09 = 2012, i.e. use a date _literal_ instead,

Comment: I tried ```cursor.execute('DELETE FROM `# Euromedica` WHERE Date > 2022-01-09T01:02:03Z')
cursor.commit()``` and it didnt help

Comment: Try using # delimiter for date value. `#2022-01-09#`.

Answer (score 4):

`Date()` is a function which returns the current system date.  If you must keep `Date` as a field name in your table, notify the db engine you mean the field name instead of the function in your SQL statement.  You can do that by enclosing the field name in square brackets or backticks, or by qualifying the name with the table name or alias.

Access SQL will interpret `2022-01-09` to mean 2022 minus 1 minus 9.  If you want it interpreted as a Date/Time value, add  `#` delimiters as the commenters suggested.

```py
cursor.execute('DELETE FROM `# Euromedica` AS e WHERE e.Date > #2022-01-09#')
```